# How do I run global code without calling the file

Tags: python

I'm writing a python application that allows users to write their own plugins and extend the core functionality I provide -

```
$ tree project_dir/
.
├── application.py
├── plugins
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── example_plugin.py
│   ├── plugin1.py
│   ├── plugin2.py
│   └── plugin3
│       ├── sounds
│       │   └── test.wav
│       └── player.py
└── plugins_manager.py
```

plugins_manager.py -

```
class Manager(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.plugins = {}

    def register_plugin(self, name, plugin_func):
        self.plugins[name] = plugin_func
```

application.py initializes `Manager` instance globally -

```
manager = Manager()

def main():
    print manager.plugins

main()
```

Each plugin is required to import the `Manager` instance from `application.py` and register itself like, plugin1.py -

```
from application import manager

PLUGIN_NAME = "AAC_Player"

def plugin_function(options):
    # do something

manager.register_plugin(PLUGIN_NAME, plugin_function)
```

Now when I run application.py, obviously nothing gets printed. How do I make the plugins register themselves (call `.register_plugin()`) at program startup?

So on that lines, a more generalised question would be - How can I make python execute a line of code that's global in a file without actually running the file?

Suggestions on improving the plugin architecture welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `__import__()` builtin to import the plugins, and then include the `register_plugin()` call in either the plugin file `example_plugin.py` or in `__init__.py` if it's a directory.

For example, let's say this is your project structure:

```
./
application.py
plugins_manager.py
plugins/
    __init__.py
    plugin1.py
    plugin2.py
    plugin3/
        __init__.py
```

Plugins have these contents:

```
$ cat plugins/plugin1.py
print 'Plugin 1'

$ cat plugins/plugin2.py
print 'Plugin 2'

$ cat plugins/plugin3/__init__.py
print 'Plugin 3'
```

In `plugins_manager.py`, identify the plugins and import them in:

```py
from os import listdir
from os.path import exists, isdir, basename, join, splitext

def is_plugin(filename):
  filepath = join('plugins', filename)
  _, ext = splitext(filepath)

  # Ignore plugins/__init__.py
  if filename == '__init__.py':
    return False

  # Find single file plugins
  if ext == '.py':
    return True

  # Find plugins packaged in directories
  if isdir(filepath) and exists(join(filepath, '__init__.py')):
    return True

  return False

plugin_names = [ splitext(p)[0] for p in listdir('plugins/') if is_plugin(p) ]
plugins = [ __import__('plugins.' + p) for p in plugin_names ]
```

Should get output similar to:

```
Plugin 1
Plugin 2
Plugin 3
```

Note that in this case the `plugins` variable contains a list of the module objects imported.

Comment: I'd like to have a setup where you can just write the plugin file conforming to certain specs, put it in plugins/ dir and forget about it. Hard-coding plugin names in __init__.py or manager.py would require modifying the file everytime a plugin is added/removed.

Comment: Also not sure about importing all the .py files. What happens when there is a folder for a plugin and multiple .py files exist in it? All will be imported unnecessarily. That's why the specs require that plugins just register a main function somewhere.

Comment: @ParinPorecha That's why I suggested you use `os.listdir` to identify plugin files, and then import the module (file name without the `.py` extension). Also, you would only search 1 level deep in the plugins directory. A directory can also be a python module if it contains a `__init__.py` file, you would put the `register_plugin()` call in that file.

Comment: how do I identify the plugin files ;) ? The names of the folders can be anything, file names can be anything, the only requirement from my side is that they register themselves somewhere in the code.

Comment: @ParinPorecha I have updated my answer with a more complete example. Unless you package each file with a configuration of some sort to identify an entry point, I am assuming each `*.py` file or directories containing a `__init__.py` under `plugins/` to be a plugin.

Comment: Fair assumption. Thanks for showing the detailed steps :) Although it would put a constraint, the overhead on my end wouldn't be much. Feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking I'd say there is no way to run code without it being invoked somehow. To do this, the running program can use

```
import importlib
```

so that once you've found the file you can import it with:

```
mod = importlib.import_module(import_name, pkg_name)
```

and if that file provides a known function (Run in this case) you can call it with:

```
mod.Run(your_args)
```

This works for Python 2.7. Version 3 might be different.